# Possible to somehow use a wildcard in playbook includes (or any workaround)?

Tags: ansible

Given a large playbook which also has many playbook includes, I would like to have some kind of abstract playbook which can be customized by concrete users. That abstract playbook should not know anything about the concrete playbooks, but include them with some wildcard. Something comparable to a [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in OOP.

It is possible in Ansible (2.2) to do this for task includes:

```
tasks:
  - include: "{{item}}"
  with_fileglob: "dir/*.yml"
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this for playbook includes:

```
- include: "{{item}}"
  with_fileglob: "dir/*.yml"
```

Ansible fails with

> ERROR! 'with_fileglob' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude

It would maybe possible to create a file which includes all existing files with some kind of pre-processor, but this seems quite error-prone.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can write shell-script wrapper that construct a playbook with multiple includes and then execute it.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: Well I have also thought about that, but I hoped there was a better solution. Anyway, I have added an answer with an ansible role which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is so far no better solution, I have created a role to create such include-files

roles/create-include/tasks/main.yml

```
- template:
    src: include.j2
    dest: "./include-{{inc_dir}}.yml"
  vars:
    idir: "{{inc_dir}}/*"
    fdir: "{{ lookup('fileglob',idir )}}"
    files: "{{ fdir.split(',') if fdir | length > 0 else []}}"
```

roles/create-include/templates/include.j2

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - debug:
      msg: "include playbook"

{% for i in files %}
- include: "{{i}}"

{% endfor %}
```

This can then be called, specifying the directory:

```
  roles:
    - {  role: create-include, inc_dir: deploy_tasks }
```

This generates the include files in the playbook root directory